# Apache TIKA - MediaDataBox iso files

Tags: apache-tika, tika-server

It seems that Apacke Tika 1.24.1  is creating lots of /tmp/MediaDataBox ISO files, and my /tmp partition gets filled up.

What is MediaDataBox ISO file used for?

Can we somehow tell Tika to save it in another directory?

Tika runs in server mode as follows:

`java -Xmx3G -jar tika-server.jar -spawnChild --host=hostname.domain.com`

Comment: How are you calling Apache Tika? Without the code / command line used, it's hard to tell you how to tweak the temp file handling

Comment: @Gagravarr : Thanks. I've updated my question.

Comment: I have a nasty feeling that the Tika Server doesn't have options to control the temp file strategy... You might be best asking on [the Apache Tika users list](https://lists.apache.org/list.html?user@tika.apache.org) for this

Comment: Tika will sometimes spool a stream to a file when the underlying parser library needs it, but generally should tidy up, so it might be a bug or a missing flag. Best ask on the user list, not all Apache Tika experts check SO (and I think the relevant 2 people don't!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example shows how to save temporary files in an alternate directory:

`java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/somewhere/tmp -jar tika-server.jar -spawnChild -JXmx3G -JDjava.io.tmpdir=/somewhere/tmp --host=hostname.domain.com`

I found useful information in [Tika Server docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/TikaServer#TikaServer-MakingTikaServerRobusttoOOMs,InfiniteLoopsandMemoryLeaks)